# Synthetic import in kotlin not working

Tags: android, kotlin

In a `Fragment`, Kotlins synthetic import for layouts provided by `Anko` isn't working. I am trying to set the visibility of the views but it says the view is null. I have the following code.

```
class HistoryFragment : Fragment(), HistoryContract.view, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<SongEntity>>{

    private lateinit var mPresenter : HistoryContract.Presenter
    private lateinit var adapter: HistoryAdapte
    private val loaderId : Int = 101

    override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<List<SongEntity>>?, data: List<SongEntity>?) {
        hideLoadingIndicator()

        if (data == null) {
            showErrorView()
        } else {
            //update the adapter
            adapter.updateDataset(data)
        }
    }

    override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<List<SongEntity>>?) {
    }

    override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<List<SongEntity>> {
       showLoadingIndicator()

       return object : AsyncTaskLoader<List<SongEntity>>(activity!!.baseContext){
            override fun loadInBackground(): List<SongEntity>? {
                return mPresenter.fetchSongs()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun showLoadingIndicator() {
        song_history_pv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun hideLoadingIndicator() {
        song_history_pv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    override fun showErrorView() {
        song_history_error_tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun hideErrorView() {
        song_history_error_tv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    override fun setPresenter(presenter: HistoryContract.Presenter) {
        mPresenter = presenter
    }

    override fun showDiscoveredSongs(songs: List<SongEntity>) {
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_history, container, false)
        loaderManager.initLoader(loaderId, null , this)
        songHistoryRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        songHistoryRv.adapter = HistoryAdapter {
            Toast.makeText(activity!!.baseContext, "${it.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        return rootView
    }
}
```

Now when I am setting the visibility of the progress view in the showLoadingIndicator function i am getting the error that the view is null.

[image: This is the null error I am getting]

Below is the layout file that I am using for the fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/songHistoryRv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/song_history_pv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_history_error_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/song_history_error"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_song_history.* is the synthetic import that I am using.

Please help me out on this. Am I missing something? I am new to kotlin.

Comment: Please post he layout along with the synthetic import statement. For me it seems like the id is missing in the layout. Otherwise it should crash much earlier.

Comment: Ok I think your issue is that you are accessing the view too early. You can't access any view before `onCreateView` returns. I think your `LoaderManager#initLoader` eventually calls one of your `HistoryContract.View` functions.

Comment: In the onCreateView functio, first the layout is inflated. The loader is called only after the views are inflated. So I don't understand how the views are not available when the loader calls them.

Comment: Because `getView()` still returns null as long as nothing is returned from `onCreateView`. Just move your Loader code to `onViewCreated` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @reVerse. This solved it

Comment: I posted it as an answer for visibility reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to access the view too early. In `#onCreateView` you are inflating your view but `Fragment#getView()` will still return null as long as you do not return the inflated view. Internally the Kotlin Android Extensions use `getView().findViewById(int)` method to bind the views the first time you are trying to access it.

**tl;dr**

To fix your issue simply return the inflated view in `#onCreateView` and move your operations regarding the `LoaderManager` to `#onViewCreated`:

```
class HistoryFragment : Fragment(), HistoryContract.view, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<SongEntity>>{

    // ...

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_history, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        loaderManager.initLoader(loaderId, null , this)
        songHistoryRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        songHistoryRv.adapter = HistoryAdapter {
            Toast.makeText(activity!!.baseContext, "${it.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I understand it now. Thanks for the answer @reVerse

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use/do code in `onViewCreated` ... Like this

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        myRequestListRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(homeActivity)
    }
```